# How do paging and segmentation work together?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, segment

I'm trying to understand how both concepts work together in memory management. I don't understand a few things and I'm not sure what I did not understand either. So I'm putting here an example scenario that would help to understand how paging and segmentation work together. Can you convert some of following logical addresses to their pysical ones and explain step by step please?

```
a) (0, 50)
b) (1,0)
c) (1,100)
d) (1,700)
e) (2,10)
f) (3,200)
* all numbers are decimal
```

Scenario:

Consider a computer that is uses segmentation and paging. The segment table of a process is the following (there are four segments):

```
Segment Base Length
0 1024 1024
1 4196 512
2 128 256
3 2048 768
```

Assume page size is 64 bytes. Assume virtual addresses are 16 bits long. Assume physical addresses are also 16 bits long. Assume a page i is located in a frame i+10 (for example, page #11 of linear logical memory is in frame #21 of physical memory). Convert the following logical addresses to their physical ones:

Comment: It is hard to tell what the question here is. One problem is that the assumptions are unrealistic. For understanding purposes, you are dealing with a computer model that was idiotic to begin with and is now, thankfully, dying out. If you want to learn about this, you should learn how paging works. Then, if you really are so inclined, learn how segments work. Then you can see how they were kluged together.

Comment: If I am right, I think you have assumed that paging and segmentation work together or are you asking that can they work together?

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation combined with paging was always a kludge. I suggest thoroughly learning how paging works without segments. For Intel, learn how it works in 64 bit mode (that finally got rid of the segment lunacy that should never have existed in the first place).

Segments in a virtual memory system are used to implement page protection (that in normal systems is implemented through page tables).